# Django Channels - Sending message to multiple channels

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I created a room dict which which stores channels of consumers which belong to a specific group, now when any consumers sends a message i want all the channels to get that message ... but I only know self.send function to send message how do i send message to all channels. Channels are stored in the following way :

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class MyWebsocketConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    room = {}
    def connect(self):
        print("Connected...",self.channel_name)
        self.group_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['group_name']
        print('Group Name...',self.group_name)

        try:
            if self.room[self.group_name]:
                self.room[self.group_name].append(self.channel_name)
        except:
            self.room[self.group_name]= [self.channel_name]


        self.accept()

        print(self.room)

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        # Help with logic here
        pass
        
    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.room[self.group_name].remove(self.channel_name)
```